# Create Column in Parse Class via code?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a situation where we have an admin server that updates a class (Class A) with some data entered from the admin server.

I have another class (Class B) that when a new Class A objectID is created I want to create just the column with that objectID in Class B..

I do not need to add any data or create a row I just want to create the column in Class B..

Any ideas?

Comment: in my case its useful, I cant talk about the whole situation but I need the column to be created for me when I do something else in my admin area, this then preps other functionality in our app to be able to store data in that column when its used.

Comment: Do you have permissions meaning clients can't just create the column when required?

Comment: this is not a client situation.. its a backend admin server where we enter some new data for a class we are storing in parse, then we have another table that needs that key added to it when this process takes place.  However I cannot find any way to just create a key w/o adding data..